# the Ringo Starr of metals

Tags: articles, definite-articles

**Palladium is *the* Ringo Starr of precious metals**

I know that it's used to compare the role of Ringo in the Beatles with the role of Palladium in the world of metals. It's like saying "Palladium is kind of an underdog, it's not being appreciated as much as others"

The sentence makes perfect sense to me, I know what it means but I can't quite comprehend the grammatical reasoning behind the article "the" before "Ringo Starr"

What rule allows this usage of the definite article "the"? How do you classify this sentence? Is it an allegory or a metaphor... or is it something else? What do you call it from the grammatical point of view? Thank you

update: here's another example of a similar sentence:
**Pollen is *the* snow of the south**

Comment: What would the sentences sound like without "the"? Would they still appear to be grammatical? What about if you replaced "the" with "a"? Are there any words that would work instead of "the"?

Comment: I know "The Ringo Starr of X" was just an example, but it is a somewhat ambiguous example of that "the X of Y" form because there is a fair amount of disagreement about how important Ringo was as a Beatle.  In my opinion he was more important than George but less important then Paul and John, yet he is also my favourite Beatle, so that means palladium is...um...something, I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Moriarty is the Napoleon of crime'

is a famous early example of the snowclone [['The Final Problem, Sir Arthur Conan Doyle](https://www.thevintagenews.com/2018/11/08/james-moriarty/)].

'X is the Y of Z'.

Y has to be famous, and unequalled (in a good, bad, or just ... er ... unequalled way) in its class, and the assertion is that X is similarly unequalled in the domain Z.

There's only one (relevant) Napoleon, Ringo Starr.... Hence the definite article is required, the implication being that X is as unique or at least as well known in their/its field Z as Y is in the unspecified relevant field.

The snowclone (and particularly its offspring) is referred to in [Wiktionary Appendix: Snowclones/X is the new Y](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Snowclones/X_is_the_new_Y):

> [The snowclone,] in its first form, "X is the Y of Z", was said by
>   Diana Vreeland as "pink is the navy blue of India" in the early 1960s.
>
> This phrase was originally used with colors, and the "X is the new Y"
>   form appeared in the 1980s with many colors being referred to as "the
>   new black".

Of course, the Conan Doyle example is far earlier.

Other examples of the original form to be found on the internet are:

- Qatar Is the Tiger of the Middle East
- fluorine is "the tiger of chemistry"
- Chicken parm sandwich with vodka sauce is the Julius Caesar of sandwiches.
- Cripps was the Churchill of the battle for national solvency.
- Bob Hawke was the Don Bradman of Australian politics.
- Rameses, who was the Louis XIV of the Egyptian race.
- [Tsar Nicholas] ... 'the Nebuchadnezzar of the North'.

Comment: 'X is the Y of Z' is exactly what I said to my friend when I was trying to explain why it happens but it didn't convince them. Is there a rule that I can refer to? I need an article of some sorts but I can't seem to find one

Comment: Isn't Sherlock Holmes a good enough authority? [:)]

Comment: The snowclone is referred to in [Wiktionary Appendix: Snowclones/X is the new Y](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Snowclones/X_is_the_new_Y): << [The snowclone, in its first form, "X is the Y of Z", was said by Diana Vreeland as "pink is the navy blue of India" in the early 1960s. This phrase was originally used with colors, and the "X is the new Y" form appeared in the 1980s with many colors being referred to as "the new black". >> Of course, the Conan Doyle example is far earlier.